# Is there a Azure Service Bus version combatible with Java 7?

Tags: java, azure, azureservicebus

The Docs of Azure Service Bus have in example picture:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues#configure-your-application-to-use-service-bus

that it uses java 8. Also code samples use Java 8 syntax and functions. I have an environment of java 7 and I am unable to get it work supposedly because java is too old.

Does anyone know a working combination of the Azure Service Bus with Java 7? I would need either the version that works for sure or answer that no version does so.

I test with newest 1.2 version available of Azure Service Bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the maven repository list of [Azure ServiceBus](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-servicebus), these versions after `0.9.8` are all built by Java 8 via check the `pom.xml` file, the version `0.9.8` is built by Java 1.6. Therefore, there is not any released jar files compiled by Java 7 or other ealier Java version for the latest version `1.x.x`.

A workaround way for yours is manually to download the source codes of [Azure ServiceBus](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java) from GitHub repo to compile it in maven by yourself. You can use JDK 7 to do it, even use JDK 8. The only changes you need is use `1.7` instead of `1.8` for the configuration of `maven-compiler-plugin` in [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/blob/dev/azure-servicebus/pom.xml), such as below.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>  <!-- 1.8 -->
        <target>1.7</target>  <!-- 1.8 -->
        <optimize>true</optimize>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Note: If using JDK 8 to do this above for compiling with the `javac` parameter `-target 1.7 -source 1.7`, you must make sure there is not any code of using Java 8 features which will cause compiler error, such as `error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7` for JDK 8. However, I roughly checked its source codes that there seems not to be. For more details about `-target` or `-source` for Javac 8, please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html.

Comment: I first added the source 1.7 to wrong place. Now placed correctly, the maven build says there are lambda expression in sources. I would need the overwrite them too, or to find another solution. I removed the tick before I find the optimal solution.

Comment: My solution was to apply next revision of Java to my Application and bypass this problemacy. Trying to convert the lambdas revealed the solution is quite tightly tied to Java 1.8 version. Java 1.8 transition was unavoidable in some phase, so why not make the effort now.

Comment: I mark this ok, because that includes using 0.9.8 as a secondary option, which is well applicable.